# Set time for scheduled task via ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, web-services, email, timer, scheduled-tasks

I have to solve the following problem. We got an ASMX web service which is requested every two minutes. If this service is not requested for ten minutes an email should be sent. We want to realize this by using the scheduled tasks. We imagined it like this

```
1. Creating a scheduled task which will send an email every ten minutes
2. If the service is requested the execution time for the task will be set to ten minutes from now and so the execution time cannot be reached
- If the service is not requested the execution time will be reached and the email is sent
```

Is there a way to solve this in ASP.NET or are there maybe better solutions?

Thanks for any response.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at the [Revalee](http://revalee.sageanalytic.com/) open source project.

You can use it to schedule web callbacks at specific times. In your case, you could schedule a web callback (10 minutes in the future) every time your web service is used. When your web service receives the callback, it can determine whether or not the service has been used recently. If the web service has been active, then the callback is ignored; if the web service has been inactive, then it can send out an email message.

For example using Revalee, you might:

1. Register a future (10 minutes from now) callback when your application launches.

   ```
   private DateTimeOffet? lastActive = null;

   private void ScheduleTenMinuteCallback()
   {
       // Schedule your callback 10 minutes from now
       DateTimeOffset callbackTime = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddMinutes(10.0);

       // Your web service's Uri
       Uri callbackUrl = new Uri("http://yourwebservice.com/ScheduledCallback/YourActivityMonitor");

       // Register the callback request with the Revalee service
       RevaleeRegistrar.ScheduleCallback(callbackTime, callbackUrl);
   }
   ```
2. Anytime your web service is used, you register another callback *and* store the date & time that your service was active as a global value.

   ```
   lastActive = DateTimeOffset.Now;

   ScheduleTenMinuteCallback();
   ```
3. Finally, when the web schedule task activates and calls your application back, then you test the value of the global

   ```
   private void YourActivityMonitor()
   {
       if (!lastActive.HasValue || lastActive.Value <= DateTimeOffset.Now.AddMinutes(-10.0))
       {
           // Send your "10 minutes has elapsed" email message
       }
   }
   ```

I hope this helps.

<sub>**Disclaimer:** I was one of the developers involved with the Revalee project. To be clear, however, Revalee is free, open source software. The source code is available on GitHub.</sub>